# express wont GET certain images on Linux. works fine on windows

Tags: javascript, html, linux, express

I am using a template to serve html code. The template code has an

```
<a href="/VacationImages/1.jpg"><img src="/SmallVacImages/1.jpg"></a>
```

attribute the file structure has a public folder and inside it has SmallVacImages and inside that is 1.jpg.

This naturally results in the image being served and there is no problem....on windows.

Now I copy my code in a folder to a flash drive and put it on my Linux machine.

Now it "Cannot GET /SmallVacImages/1.jpg"/

My index.html can load images just fine from the public/images folder. but it can't load from the public/SmallVacImages folder. The template file cannot load any image file from the images or smallvacimages folders. but it can load some other files in the public folder, like text files. WHAT THE HELL?

This is some of the server code

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var filename = (req.url);
    var doNext = true;
    if (filename === '/')
    {
        log();
        doNext = true;
    }
    else if(filename.split('?')[0] === "/VacationPics")
    {
        var number = filename.split('?')[1];
        Template(req,res,filename,number);
        doNext = false;
    }
    if(doNext == true)
    next();
});

 app.use(express.static('public')); // The Express routes handler.
 app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Listening on port "+PORT));
```

Any ideas I'm completely confused by this.

Comment: Do the webserver has permission to read from the folder `/SmallVacImages `?

Comment: I should add i have added and subtracted the "/" in front of the link to no avail.

Comment: Which type of webServer do you use?

Comment: Is the `SmallVacImages` folder on the machines root or the web directory root? with outer words is the HTML file and the `SmallVacImages` folder in the same directory?

Comment: Figured it out. it was the difference between JPG and jpg.

Comment: Ok must languishes is case difference and will not see JPG and jpg as the same.

Answer (score 1):

It was because on windows jpg == JPG and on linux jpg != JPG. thanks for the help though. I tried to solve this for hours but 10 minutes after I post this I find the answer.